# How to heat a gas to ~3000K?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, experimental-technique

I'm not much of an experimentalist, but I was wondering if there are any well-known, and relatively straightforward ways of heating gasses to high temperatures (~3000K). Say, I have a sealed ceramic bottle with a gas inside. How could I heat it up without melting whatever it is I'm using to heat it up with?

This is using a non-nuclear power source.

Comment: How much gas, and at what pressure? If the answer is "not much," would the buffer vapor near the filament of an incandescent light bulb work? If not, we might need more information about *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Friendly reminder: comments are for improving the question, not for brief answers.

Answer (score 1):

Rapid compression (like in diesel engines), but the gas would immediate cool because of contact with the walls.

For an ideal gas, adiabatic compression gives
$$TV^{\gamma - 1} = {\rm constant},$$
where $\gamma = c_p/c_v = 1.40$ for air around room temperature. This will be different at high temperatures but let us ignore that and estimate a compression ratio $r=V_1/V_2$ to achieve 3000 K starting from 300 K. That will be $r^{0.40} = 10$ which gives $r =10^{5/2}= 316.$

So this is not very realistic.

Answer (score 0):

An old fashioned tungsten wire can be heated up to 3000K. Perhaps you could use a thorium oxide container. Just brainstorming though.